# Asp.Net Page.Master.FindControl always returns null inside static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the Master page Label Control but I am getting only null.

> Master Page:

```
<div class="content">
                    <div class="container">

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtUName" runat="server" Text="Raji"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Style="padding: 10px; font-size: medium; font-family: Calibri" align="left" Text="Save"/>
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

> Child Page Code behind:

```
 public static void ClientMessage(Page p, string message)
 {
  Label _lblClientMessage_ = p.Master.FindControl("Label1") as Label;     
 }
```

Kindly assist me to get this master page Label control in child page.

Comment: You should think if it's a good idea to hardwire this page with the master-page. Also, if you really want it you should provide a property(for example `ClientMessage`) in the master which gets and sets the text. Then you dont need to find this label with a specific ID but you just need to cast the `Master` property to the real type:  `((TypeOfMaster)p.Master).ClientMessage = message;`

Comment: Find control doesn't always dive down as deep as you might think. You might need to start at a "lower" point in the HTML (lower than master)

Comment: >firstly 

// Get a reference to the master page
MasterPage ctl00 = FindControl("ctl00") as MasterPage;

// Get a reference to the ContentPlaceHolder
ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = ctl00.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;

// Reference the Label controls
Label ResultsLabel = MainContent.FindControl("Label1") as Label;